# Use a function builded for UICollectionView inside the function UITableView heightForRowAt (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

I'm a beginner and i would like to know how can i add this function that was created for a UICollectionView

```
func heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath, withWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

        let place = places[indexPath.row]
        let annotationPadding = CGFloat(5)

        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        let commentHeight = place.heightForComment(font, width: width)

        let height = annotationPadding + commentHeight + annotationPadding

        return height
    }
```

inside

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {


    return 130
}
```

since unlike the collectionView in the tableView i only need of the height value because there aren't columns

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my Mac right now, but why not just return your heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath() function inside your tableView() function? I'm thinking as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    //you'll have to set your indexPath and withWidth parameters
    return heightForAnnotationAtIndexPath(indexPath, withWidth)

}
```

They both return CGFloats for you, so that should work for you.